# LDAP filter syntax not working using when using groups search filter

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-query

LDAP filter syntax is not working when I am using groups.  I can filter to the OU level, but not when using groups nested inside that OU.

User Base DN looks like this:

> cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=domain,dc=local

Search scope is "*Search whole subtree below Base DN*"

Group Base DN is:

> cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=domain,dc=local

My Search Filter is

```
(&(objectclass=groups)(cn=my_users))
```

I'm using OpenLDAP as the LDAP back-end.  When executing the query I am getting "No groups found" when I know the group exists.  I've researched and reviewed my syntax over and over again and still getting the same error.  Any help?

Comment: You will have to post your real code and the layout or LDIF of a sample group showing a user member.

Comment: Thank you but I got my question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search Filter is wrong.  Use instead:

> (&(objectclass=groupOfNames)(cn=my_users))

Comment: Or `groupOfUniqueNames`, or `organizationalRole`, or .... Or do you have second sight? And the `cn` part is wrong as well, but also in a way we cannot intuit.